# Can I draw 2 weapons with the same hand (throwing one and then drawing another) using the Dual Wielder feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons, two-weapon-fighting

I had an idea for a level 5 fighter with the Dual Wielder feat that used a melee weapon in the off-hand (whip) and used a thrown weapon (javelin) in the main hand.

My question is: With the main hand empty and a whip in the off hand, can my fighter draw a javelin, throw it, draw another, throw that one, and finish with an off hand attack with whip?

The main point being: Can you draw 2 weapons with the same hand using the Dual Wielder feat?

Answer (score 21):

## You cannot split the object interaction.

The third bullet point of [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/customization-options#DualWielder) says:

> You can draw or stow two one-handed weapons when you would normally be able to draw or stow only one.

A character gets one free object interaction per turn. Dual Wielder allows the character to use it to draw two weapons - it does not give the character two object interactions.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that a second object interaction requires the use of your action, and that extra attack allows multiple attacks per action, not multiple actions. So much confusion about that.

Comment: Thrown weapons are signifcantly inferior to bows, I do not know if it is an intentional design decision, or just an accident.